# transform touch/click coordinates(2D) into 3d coordinates

Tags: xna

I would like to convert touch/click input (2D coordinates) to 3D coordinates by dropping the Z axis (would like to move only up/down, left/right (Z is the axis for depth).

The problem is that the coordinates i get from input (2d) aren't corelated with the 3d actual space.

Does XNA provide a way to do this?

Comment: Just a guess, mouse ray can be the answer (:

Comment: @Gtoknu thanks! i'll give it a try! i'll be back with feedback

Answer (score 1):

You want to have a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.viewport.unproject.aspx

Comment: this only shows if a touch input intersects an object. i actually need to generate the next position (while dragging) for the object. i solved it with some good ol' fashion vector geometry : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100439/determine-where-a-vector-will-intersect-a-plane

Comment: Using unproject from the near plane and far plane you get a line segment that spans the entire camera's view, you could then move your object along that line segment. However, as you've said, you've already solved the problem.